# Review edit button sometimes seems not working

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits

I think I'm not the first to see this kind of problem, but cannot find a previous question on MetaSO explaining-it. So, when I do reviewing First posts / Late answer; sometimes, I click on the `edit` button, but nothing is happening (just scrolling page to the top).

It's show nothing special, like maybe `you cannot edit because another is pending` or something like that; just scrolling top, without opening editor.

I tried to show some logs to have an Idea why was wrong (it's not the first time that's occurs), but nothing seems interesting:

```
14:35:14.841 Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js”.  first-posts:1
14:35:14.915 SyntaxError: function statement requires a name[Learn More]  analytics.js:1:436
14:35:17.987 This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!  17143880
```

(Nothing more appearing when I click on edit button)

Because it's maybe a bug, I precise that I'm using **Firefox** on **Ubuntu 16.04 x64**.

Here a screenshot taken one time that occur (nothing special visible, no blocked popup by navigator, I've disabled AdBlock on SO also):

[image: Screenshot]

For now, in that case, I'm only able to <kbd>Skip</kbd> the question (I can also say <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> but not correct when edit is needed).

Comment: Link to the review please?

Comment: Can't have it (or don't know how), was Skipped so; Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17143880 (screenshot)

Comment: There was a suggested edit that was open for 31 minutes.  That was probably the reason.  A popup would be nice

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answer, so I will continue to skipping these questions so :P

Comment: Just encountered the same issue, I clicked on the question and pressed Edit there, showing the message that another edit was pending. Would be really nice if that message could be shown in the review queue too.